# Unable to access Eureka dashboard inside a docker container

Tags: docker, firewall, netflix-eureka, firewalld

I am setting up a docker container test environment of a Spring Cloud Config Server and Eureka Discovery Service to a server running Oracle Linux 8. Before anything else, I added the following port from **firewalld** to allow inbound (reloaded and restarted the firewall after):

- 8086: Spring Cloud Config Server
- 8087: Eureka Discovery Service

I can confirm the port were added successfully

[image]

Next, I created a docker network: `docker network create net-test` then build and run the Spring Cloud Config Server and it's accessible via my local computer when I tried to curl: `curl http://192.168.1.100:8086/actuator` (dummy) as it displays the actuator details.

Next, I ran the Eureka and checked the logs and its getting the application properties from the Spring Cloud Config Server.
[image]

However, I am unable to access it via browser or curl (`curl http://192.168.1.100:8087`)
`Failed to connect to 192.168.1.100 port 8087: Connection refused`

This is the application.properties of Eureka

```
"source": {
     "server.port": 8087,
     "spring.application.name": "discovery",
     "eureka.client.fetchRegistry": false,
     "eureka.client.registerWithEureka": false,
     "eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone": "http://192.168.1.100:8087/eureka", # IP of host machine
     "eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address": true,
     "spring.security.user.name": "test1",
     "spring.security.user.password": "test1"
}
```

UPDATE:

- This is the nmap result for 8086 and 8087
  [image]
  [image]
- This is from the iptables
  [image]

**UPDATE**
Here are the Docker commands/setup I used

- Docker network: `docker network create net-test`
- Dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY target/discoveryservice-0.0.1-snapshot.jar discoveryservice.jar
EXPOSE 8087
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "discoveryservice.jar"]
```

- Docker Build: `docker build --tag=discovery-service --force-rm=true .`
- Docker Run: `docker run -p 8087:8087 --network=net-test --name=discovery-service discovery-service`

Comment: What are your run commands for Docker and what are your Docker images?(have you exposed port in the Dockerfile of Eureka?)

Comment: Hi @Niklas, I have updated my question to include my Docker configs/commands used. Kindly scroll above.

Comment: there should be a config for Eureka, `server.address`, could you try changing it to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: @PapEr, yes I have but with localhost. `server.address=localhost`

Comment: that‘s my point, change it to `0.0.0.0` and try again, it should possibly work

Comment: `0.0.0.0` allows connections from everywhere, be careful with that on production systems.

Comment: If you open bash on your Spring container, and try to curl Eureka from there, what happens?

Comment: @PapEr and @Niklas, I have updated `server.address=0.0.0.0` and inside the container I did `wget http://username:password@localhost:8087` works. But outside it says, `Read error (Connection reset by peer)

Comment: forgive me if this is a stupid question, how did you change your config, and did you  restart you server after changing the config

Comment: @PapEr, I edited my ‘discovery-service.yml’ located in a test branch git repo online. Then hit the Config Server’s refresh endpoint. I can verify the update was received by eureka server app from logs ‘keys refreshed’. I also did stop/start config server and eureka to be sure

Comment: I don't understand why the address must be `0.0.0.0` just to access the eureka dashboard (container) within the docker network or docker host. While you can hit the config server refresh endpoint from docker host/remote with configured `address: localhost` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @[PapEr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4242336/paper)'s comment: You have to turn `server.address` to `0.0.0.0`.

#### Why?

Listing on ports must be bind to a host. [Read this for more informations.](https://www.ateam-oracle.com/listen-addresses)
With the address you can reduce the machines, which can talk to the port.

#### In Docker?

Normally you don't know the docker-ip, so you can't just set the address of your docker-container. You have only the choice between `localhost` or `0.0.0.0`.
With `localhost` only connection from the inside of your docker-container are possible. In other words: No other applications can talk to your container, if you set `localhost`.
Since your containers have their own network and ip, I don't see any reason why `address=0.0.0.0` is bad idea. Also in production.

Comment: Hi @akop, I will try this out. Does this mean I also need to update my `"eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone": "http://username:password@localhost:8087/eureka",` to use `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: No, `0.0.0.0` is a "catch all ip-address" and you can't use it as address in webbrowser. For `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone` you have to configure the host for eureka. In your case (you want to access it on your local machine) `localhost` is fine.

Comment: I've updated the config to this `server.address=0.0.0.0` and `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://${spring.security.user.name}:${spring.security.user.name}@localhost:8087/eureka` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I went inside the container I did `wget http://username:password@localhost:8087` works. But outside it says, `Read error (Connection reset by peer)`

Comment: It seems, that new config may not be applied correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230219/discussion-between-akop-and-rye).